# Rss Parser error for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I'm working on making a Rss feed for my asp.net project and I found a solution for it however it only worked when I was testing it on my computer and as I uploaded it on the server it stopped working with a parser error...
I first thought it's about debug mode but I omited that part and I still get the error...
this is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" debug="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="mysite.feed.Default" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

and this is the aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace mysite.feed
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        db_mysite context=new db_mysiteEntities();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
            XmlTextWriter objX = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            objX.WriteStartDocument();
            objX.WriteStartElement("rss");
            objX.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");
            objX.WriteStartElement("channel");


            objX.WriteElementString("title", "mysite.com Rss Feed");
            objX.WriteElementString("link", "mysite.com/");
            objX.WriteElementString("description", "");
            objX.WriteElementString("language", "en-us");
            objX.WriteElementString("ttl", "60");
            objX.WriteElementString("image", "");
            objX.WriteElementString("lastBuildDate", String.Format("{0:R}", DateTime.Now));

            var b = (from c in context.News where c.IsActive == true  select c).ToList();

            foreach (var newse in b)
            {
                int txt = newse.NewsID;
                var g = (from c in context.News_Group_Connections
                         where c.NewsID == txt
                         join r in context.News_Group on c.NewsGroupID equals r.NewsGroupID
                         select r.NewsGroupTitle).First();

                objX.WriteStartElement("item");
                objX.WriteElementString("title", newse.NewsTitle);
                objX.WriteElementString("author", "VBasic.net");
                objX.WriteElementString("link", newse.NewsLinkAddress);
                objX.WriteStartElement("guid");
                objX.WriteAttributeString("isPermaLink", "true");
                objX.WriteString("mysite.com/");
                objX.WriteEndElement();
                //objX.WriteElementString("pubDate", DateTime.Parse(newse.NewsDate.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                objX.WriteElementString("pubDate", String.Format("{0:R}", newse.NewsDate));
                objX.WriteStartElement("category");
                objX.WriteString(g);
                objX.WriteEndElement();
                objX.WriteElementString("description", newse.NewsDescription);
                objX.WriteEndElement();
            }
            //while (dr.Read())
            //{
            //    objX.WriteStartElement("NewsTitle");

            //    objX.WriteEndElement();
            //    objX.WriteElementString("description", dr["Article"].ToString().Substring(0, 100) + "..");
            //    objX.WriteEndElement();
            //}

            objX.WriteEndElement();
            objX.WriteEndElement();
            objX.WriteEndDocument();
            objX.Flush();
            objX.Close();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks...

---

edit: error occurs on line one and the message is this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The file '/feed/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" debug="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="mysite.feed.Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="none" %>


Source File: /feed/default.aspx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34209
```

Comment: What's the error message, and what line in the above code is it happening on?

Comment: is on line 1...I added the message as an edit to my question

Comment: Ok how about changing my long question to "how to make an easy Rss feed for Asp.net?"